# ndk-build error: no such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have made a project with OpenCV and i need to use Native Code for realtime processing purpose, following the guide on this book [opencv3](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/android-application-programming-opencv-3), here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := FinalCamJNI
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lstdc++ # C++ standard library
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog # Android logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz # zlib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := opencv_calib3d
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencv_features2d
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencv_flann
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencv_imgproc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencv_core

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FinalCamJNI.cpp RecolorRCFilter.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_calib3d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_calib3d.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_features2d
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_features2d.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_flann
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_flann.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_imgproc.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libopencv_core.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and here is my Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static # GNU STL
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti –fexceptions # RTTI, exceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

I'm facing this error when performing ndk-build:

[image: NDK Error]

I have checked the directory, and ensured that i have prepared all the code file 
in jni folder.

In addition, here is my implementation file:

FinalCamJNI.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "RecolorRCFilter.hpp"

using namespace finalcam;
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_nahuy_hcmus_finalcam_filters_newSelf(
JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{
 RecolorRCFilter *self = new RecolorRCFilter();
 return (jlong)self;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_nahuy_hcmus_finalcam_filters_deleteSelf(
 JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong selfAddr)
{
 if (selfAddr != 0)
 {
 RecolorRCFilter *self = (RecolorRCFilter *)selfAddr;
 delete self;
 }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_nahuy_hcmus_finalcam_filters_apply(
 JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong selfAddr, jlong srcAddr,jlong dstAddr)
{
 if (selfAddr != 0)
 {
 RecolorRCFilter *self = (RecolorRCFilter *)selfAddr;
 cv::Mat &src = *(cv::Mat *)srcAddr;
 cv::Mat &dst = *(cv::Mat *)dstAddr;
 self->apply(src, dst);
 }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

RecolorRCFilter.hpp:

```
#ifndef RECOLOR_RC_FILTER
#define RECOLOR_RC_FILTER

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

namespace finalcam {
class RecolorRCFilter
{
public: // All subsequent methods or variables are public.
 void apply(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst);
private: // All subsequent methods or variables are private.
 cv::Mat mChannels[4];
};
} // namespace secondsight
#endif // RECOLOR_RC_FILTER
```

RecolorRCFilter.cpp:

```
#include "RecolorRCFilter.hpp"

using namespace finalcam;

void RecolorRCFilter::apply(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst)
{
 cv::split(src, mChannels);
 cv::Mat g = mChannels[1];
 cv::Mat b = mChannels[2];
 // dst.g = 0.5 * src.g + 0.5 * src.b
 cv::addWeighted(g, 0.5, b, 0.5, 0.0, g);
 // dst.b = dst.g
 g.copyTo(b);
 cv::merge(mChannels, 4, dst);
}
```

Can anyone explain me why this happens and what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: the screenshot is an evidence that Application.mk was not used; anyways, to get better understanding of what's going on, run `ndk-build V=1`

Comment: maybe your mistake is that you run `ndk-build` from the wrong directory. Try to run it from **app\src\main**

Comment: @Alex Cohn I have changed running ndk-build from app\src\main and still facing the same error, after run ndk-build V=1 the path of my source file which is showed is exactly the same as my file path.

Comment: does it still speak about **APP_PLATFORM=android-24**?

Comment: @AlexCohn it disappeared.

Comment: I suspect these two strange characters before the word "exception". Maybe your cpp file is corrupt (e.g. has a Unicode prefix that the compiler cannot understand). Try to replace the cpp file with empty text file (zero bytes length) to confirm my suspicion.